# Cannot setf an element of a list

Tags: common-lisp

I'm very new at lisp and I'm trying to make a basic chess game, however I appear to have failed at the first hurdle. Every time I attempt to run the function `(move... )` I get the error:

```
*** - FUNCTION: undefined function (SETF GET-ELEMENT)
```

Here is the code:

```
(defparameter *board* '(
                       (♜ ♞ ♝ ♛ ♚ ♝ ♞ ♜)
                       (♟ ♟ ♟ ♟ ♟ ♟ ♟ ♟)
                       (☐ ☐ ☐ ☐ ☐ ☐ ☐ ☐)
                       (☐ ☐ ☐ ☐ ☐ ☐ ☐ ☐)
                       (☐ ☐ ☐ ☐ ☐ ☐ ☐ ☐)
                       (☐ ☐ ☐ ☐ ☐ ☐ ☐ ☐)
                       (♙ ♙ ♙ ♙ ♙ ♙ ♙ ♙)
                       (♖ ♘ ♗ ♕ ♔ ♗ ♘ ♖)
                       ))

(defun print-rows (board)
  "Print each element of LIST on a line of its own."
  (mapcar #'print board))

(defun get-element (x y table)
  (nth x (nth y table)))

(defun move (x1 x2 y1 y2)
  (setf (get-element x2 y2 *board*) (get-element x1 y1 *board*)))
```

I'm pretty sure I have a fundamental misunderstanding of lisp which is why this is not working, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Don't modify literal data

First, when you define ***board*** as **'(...)**, you've made its value a *literal object*. The consequences of attempting to modify literal data are undefined, so it's something you want to avoid.  Instead, define ***board*** as **(copy-tree '(...))**.  That's not the primary issue, but it's an important one.

### (get-element …) isn't a [place](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/05_a.htm)

The first (and third, fifth, etc.) arguments to **setf** are [*places*](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/05_a.htm). With your current code, **(get-element …)** isn't a place.  The definition isn't bad (though for random two-dimensional access, it would probably be better to use an array and **aref**).  You can make **(get-element …)** be a setf-able place in a few ways.  First, you could make **get-element** a macro:

```
(defmacro get-element (x y table)
  `(nth ,x (nth ,y ,table)))
```

That's a very quick solution, but it comes at a cost, because now you can't, for instance, do something like **(map 'get-element '(1 2) '(3 4) (make-list 2 :initial-element table))**, because **get-element** is no longer a function.  A better bet is just to define the **setf** function that would make this work, by exploiting the fact that **(nth …)** *is* a place that can be used with **setf**:

```
(defun (setf get-element) (value x y table)
  (setf (nth x (nth y table)) value))
```

This kind of function is described in the HyperSpec:

> #### [5.1.2.9 Other Compound Forms as Places](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/05_abi.htm)
>
> For any other compound form for which the operator is a symbol f, the
>   setf form expands into a call to the function named (setf f). The
>   first argument in the newly constructed function form is newvalue and
>   the remaining arguments are the remaining elements of place.

That means **(setf (get-element …) value)** gets turned into **(funcall #'(setf get-element) value …)**, and that's precisely the function we have just defined.

### Example

```
CL-USER> (defun (setf get-element) (value x y table)
           (setf (nth x (nth y table)) value))
; (SETF GET-ELEMENT)

CL-USER> (let ((board (copy-tree '((1 2 3)
                                   (4 5 6)))))
           (setf (get-element 1 1 board) 'x)
           board)
; ((1 2 3) (4 X 6))
```